# How can an app get in a state where all user-defined publications don't respond?

Tags: meteor

Somehow my app got in a state in which the only publication that returned data was the meteor autoupdate collection (see below websocket traffic). When I did `mup restart`, it was back to normal. What are the possible reasons for this happening? I had a `console.log` at the top of the `data` publish function, and was not seeing anything printed to the logs.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going by the order of subscriptions one of the 'data', houston or your login service configuration is not responding. There may be something going on blocking the event loop, and blocking everything else.

Judging from the collections which work it may be that your mongodb is taking a very long time to respond or is jammed up. You may want to check the server side to narrow down the specific issue. If you're using mup you may want to try using compose.io or a 3rd party mongodb service instead of the one on your server.

Very intensive background operations can do it too, in particular lots of db operations that include `remove`. But it can happen in general due to the mongodb 'lock' issue

Comment: Thanks! There weren't any other clients using it, and no background jobs running. What's the best way to "check the server side"? A cron that tests meteor's connection to mongo by seeing if a query returns?

Comment: Also, note that the DB is separate. The `mup restart` was only restarting the `meteor` process.

Comment: @Loren if there are no errors on the server side indicating a db lock or timeouts then the best way is to check with a query. Its quite a difficult issue to get a hold of actually, especially if its a shared database somehow.

Comment: @Loren you may also have an issue limited RAM if you're not using the oplog. DigitalOcean squeezes meteor pretty hard on the $5 instance if you're using that.